# Why is my storyboard not loaded?

Tags: objective-c, storyboard

I am trying to open a separate storyboard using code for a specific login task.

I created the storyboard and the instance class as follows

```
+ (instancetype)newStoryboardInstance {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:NSStringFromClass([self class]) bundle:[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]]];
    AdyenLoginViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];

    return viewController;
}
```

I am then calling this from another class like this

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    if([NWTillHelper isDebug] == 1) {
        NSLog(@"%s entered", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    }
    [AdyenLoginViewController newStoryboardInstance];
}
```

But the loginController is never shown and no error messages are shown, it just finishes loading my normal storyboard and then stops.

The storyboard name etc is correct as per the class name and no compiler errors or warnings are shown

How can I make it load my specific storyboard?

Comment: is AdyenLoginViewController is initial view controller ?

Comment: Yes it is the only viewcontroller in that storyboard

Comment: [AdyenLoginViewController newStoryboardInstance] here it will only return view controller did you push or present it anywhere?

Comment: put a breakpoint in the newStoryboardInstance function and check it the viewController is initialised..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using navigation controller then viewDidAppear will look like this :-

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    if([NWTillHelper isDebug] == 1) {
       NSLog(@"%s entered", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    }
    if([AdyenLoginViewController newStoryboardInstance]) {
       [self.navigationContoller pushViewController:[AdyenLoginViewController newStoryboardInstance] animated:true];
    }

}
```

Or you can present the viewController like this :-

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    if([NWTillHelper isDebug] == 1) {
       NSLog(@"%s entered", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    }
    if([AdyenLoginViewController newStoryboardInstance]) {
       [self presentViewController:[AdyenLoginViewController newStoryboardInstance] animated:true completion:^{

       }];
    }

}
```